# Is it possible to use two alieses for the same column in a query?

Tags: mysql

### Context

Let's say I have a field called `A` of type `CHAR` and a field called `B` of type `INT`.

I'm migrating field `A` to a new type by creating a new field and copying the values around. The field is called `B`.

At the moment the two field coexist while I am copying the data from a column to another and the application code has a fallback so if column B contains a value then return B, otherwise return the value from A and convert the value at the application level.

### The Problem

Now I would like to rename `B` to `A` but I'm finding it really difficult to find a solution that doesn't require many deploys by creating another temp column and doing a switch of columns again.

### Questions

Is there anyway where I can say something like `select (int(A) or B) as B from table`?

Or do you have any ideas on making this a little bit smoother?

Comment: Can you add a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 with some sample data to your post?

Answer (score 1):

No you caqn't  have two columns with the same name.

What you can do is

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1(a char(2), b INT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES('1',5)
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE tab1 CHANGE a a1 char(2)
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE tab1 CHANGE b a int;
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE tab1 CHANGE a1 b char(2)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tab1
> ```
>
> ```
> b  |  a
> :- | -:
> 1  |  5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=09ac1e49703f42ca6cb92cfb3e6ce237)*